# Can crystal reports get data from an object data source?

Tags: crystal-reports, ssrs-2008, objectdatasource

Can crystal reports get data from an object data source instead of a database? I am using the crystal reports that comes with vs2008. I am coding in c# 3.5.

I would like to use an object data source that returns a List< MyClass>.

For when we migrate to ssrs in the future, Can ssrs 2008 get data from this object data source ?

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you asking about the capabilities of Crystal Reports or SQL Server?

Comment: What kind of object data source are we talking about? If your data source can be exported via ODBC or XML, then yes, Crystal can import it.

Comment: I am asking first about Crystal. I would like to use an object data source that returns a List<MyClass>. So are you saying that if export my object data source to an xml file, I could use that as my input in crystal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetDataSource has an overload excepting ICollection parameters. Using it, you can bind simple collections of objects to CR. But this isn't that flexible than using data sets. With data sets you can bind multiple related tables and build reports of a higher complexity.

The migration of your server has no impact on CR, because SetDataSource only works with disconnected objects such as data sets or object data sources.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that, but you have to wrap the objects in an array :

```
// my crystal report
Rpt rpt = new Rpt();


AirLine lAirLine = (AirLine)cmbAirLine.SelectedItem;

// I added two objects as datasources in report designer

// here aWB.AWBPieceList is List<AWBPiece> where 'AWBPiece' is some class.
rpt.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource( AWBPieceList.ToArray() );

// the second : objects are mapped to tables by crystal report.
rpt.Database.Tables[1].SetDataSource( new AirLine[] { lAirLine } );
```

Comment: +1 for rpt.Database.Tables. In some old reports which are using multiple DataTables in a DataSet, I have been able to replace just one of the data sources with a list of objects without rewriting the whole report.

Comment: Also it is not necessary to convert the list to an array CR (at least v13) will happily use any enumerable.